# VBA the sum of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sum `Cells(2,6)` to `Cells(4,6)` with each other.

this is my code:

```
kosten = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(4, 6)))
Cells(3, 10) = kosten
```

but the output is `0`, meanwhile it's supposed to be `1406`.

can somebody help me please?

Comment: Why not just put the sum formula in `Cell(3, 10)`? So `Cell(3,10).formula="SUM(....)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code changing the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LOf()

    Dim kosten As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change if needed
        kosten = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(4, 6)))
        .Range(3.10).Value=kosten
    End With

End Sub
```